# Calculated default datetime parameters for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create stored procedure which will return rows `WHERE` Creation date between 'start' and 'end' value. But I want to consider possibility of empty values for stored procedure, so I need default values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProjectsRatingByCreationDateInterval]
    @Start DATETIME = GETDATE,
    @End DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
AS
    SELECT 
        ID, ProjectName, Rating, CreationDateTime 
    FROM 
        Projects 
    WHERE 
        CreationDateTime BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

Tried to do this like that but received this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

It references the `DATEADD` function call in the `@End` declaration.

Comment: You've got a good answer, but please note that `@End` should be bigger than `@Start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the value as Null and set inside procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProjectsRatingByCreationDateInterval]

    @Start DATETIME  NULL,
    @End DATETIME NULL
AS

IF @Start is null   
    SET @Start = GETDATE()

IF @End is null     
SET @End = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())

    SELECT 
        ID, ProjectName, Rating, CreationDateTime 
    FROM 
        Projects 
    WHERE 
        CreationDateTime BETWEEN @Start and @End
```

Comment: Or easier - `select @start = ISNULL(@Start, GetDate()), @end = ISNULL(@End, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())`

Comment: Correct me If i am wrong, In your query the SET operation for @ start and @ end will run for sure even if it having value. But here it will be skipped if it have value already.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here

```
@Start DATETIME = GETDATE,
```

getdate is a function so write it as GETDATE()

```
@Start DATETIME = GETDATE(),
```

The Procedure look like that

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProjectsRatingByCreationDateInterval]
        @Start DATETIME = GETDATE(),
        @End DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            ID, ProjectName, Rating, CreationDateTime 
        FROM 
            Projects 
        WHERE 
            CreationDateTime BETWEEN @Start AND @End
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your need.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProjectsRatingByCreationDateInterval]
    @Start DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    @End DATETIME = NULL
AS
    SELECT 
        ID, ProjectName, Rating, CreationDateTime 
    FROM 
        Projects 
    WHERE 
        CreationDateTime BETWEEN @Start AND (CASE WHEN @End IS NULL THEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @Start) ELSE @End END)
```

Comment: This is shorter, but SQL Server will find it more difficult to optimize.

Comment: may be depending upon Projects table usages of and design. But the case sufficing his requirement with neat & clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You also can make use of `ISNULL()` function to default to a value if whatever has been passed is a `NULL`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetProjectsRatingByCreationDateInterval
    @Start DATETIME NULL, @End DATETIME NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Start = ISNULL(@Start, GETDATE());
    SET @End = ISNULL(@Start, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()));

    SELECT ID, ProjectName, Rating, CreationDateTime
    FROM Projects
    WHERE CreationDateTime BETWEEN @Start AND @End;
END;
```